# Unexpected key value pairs wrapping my state when using Redux mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I have been working on a React Native app with Firebase and Redux for a few weeks now without any issues with respect to my Redux usage. However, while I was working on something today I began to see this strange problem that seemed to start happening for no reason I can discern.

When I login with Firebase I call a Redux action to set my user object in the store like so.

```
await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass)
  .then(async (userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    const token = await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken();
    props.setUser({
      id: user['uid'],
      email: user['email'],
      token: token
    });
    props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  })
```

Here are the corresponding action and reducer.

```
export const setUser = (payload: User) => (
    {
        type: 'SET_USER',
        payload: payload
    }
);
```

```
const userReducer = async (state = INITIAL_USER_STATE, action: { type: string; payload: User; }) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
    case 'SET_USER':
      alert('payload: ' + JSON.stringify(action.payload));
      return action.payload;
  }
};
```

You'll notice I've put an alert in the reducer to make sure the state is getting set how I intend (and it is).

[user object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnBUc.png)

In one of my components I want access to this user object. So, I make use of `connect()` like so.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: { user: User }) => {
  const { user } = state;
  return { user };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PlaidBackDrop);
```

In the same file I alert the user object with `alert(JSON.stringify(props.user));`. Here is what I get (yikes!).

[what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y94ga.png)

So I can add this random `_z` to my code and it works again. But I really, really don't want to do that.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: { user: User }) => {
  const { user } = state;
  return { user: user['_z'] };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PlaidBackDrop);
```

To make matters worse, sometimes the state I get is different. Here are two more random sets of keys and values wrapping my object that I got without changing anything in my code.

[what the heck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeZeh.png)
[seriously now its nesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1YcH.png)

So, sometimes I get the object, sometimes I get the action and sometimes I get the  object wrapped in these inexplicable `_x`, `_y` and `_z` things.

Can someone please help? :)

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing `redux` and `react-redux`. I have tried re-building my app. I have tried restarting my laptop. I have tried simplifying my reducer, getting rid of the async call to `auth.currentUser?.getIdToken()` on the login page and just indexing like `user: user['_z']['_z']['_z']`.

Comment: The only issue I see in the code is a state mutation in the user reducer with `state = action.payload;`. Other than this the rest seems fine. Are you *sure* your response values for the `setUser` payload are what you expect? Can you create a ***running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Do a search in your code to see where you're dispatching whatever action triggers that reducer. Somewhere along the line you're dispatching it with the _x, _y, _z object (and then once you have that object in there, you'll dispatch it again later, resulting in the nested version). This can be tricky to catch in tests, because your tests usually assume you're dispatching the right thing. You do have tests, right? Right? The nice thing about having tests is you can be really sure that if you do pass the right action in, the reducer always creates the right format, so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese I have addressed this state mutation in my code. I will update the question to reflect this. woops. I will get back to you on whether I can create a running sandbox for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to convert the firebase objects to plain objects by calling `.toJson` on them.